# There is a shorter/elegant/efficient way of writing this?

Tags: r

This R code works, but the for  loop looks too long and ugly, and I had read that using for loops is not advised in R.

What I want to do is to copy vectors of varying length from the list of vectors HaarData@W to the rows of the matrix MyMatrix.

Since the vectors length is shorter than the number of columns in the matrix, I want to duplicate the values to fill the row.

The vectors have length 2<sup>z</sup> z ∈ ℤ , and the matrix row length needs to be n such 2<sup>z</sup> ≤ n

```
library(wavelets)


Data <- seq(1, 16)

n <- as.integer(log2(length(Data)))
#Data <- seq(1, 2 ^ n, 1)
HaarData <- dwt(Data, filter = "haar")


#Square matrix to write data
MyMatrix <- matrix(, nrow = n, ncol = 2 ^ n)


row <- 0 #row counter
for (vector in HaarData@W) {
    row <- row + 1
    duplication <- (2 ^ n) / length(vector)
    newRow <- c(rep(vector, each = duplication))
    MyMatrix[row,] <- newRow
}
```

Comment: Questions about making running code look prettier aren't exactly on topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe [codereview.se] is a better place.

Comment: try `do.call(rbind,list(a=1:3, b=1:2, c=1:5))`

Comment: @Jimbou Do you mean replacing the for loop with `MyMatrix <- do.call(rbind, do.call(rep(?, each = n/length(?)),HaarData@W))` How do you specify "`?`"

Comment: Use directly the list `HaarData@W`. Try to include your data using `dput()` and your expected output. I can't install additional packages right now, so it would be easier to help you this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do the operation in first place, nevertheless the following would be my approach:

```
library(wavelets)
library(microbenchmark)

Data <- seq(1, 32)
n <- as.integer(log2(length(Data)))

HaarData <- dwt(as.numeric(Data), filter = "haar")

# Abstract operation in the loop in a function, no side effects
duplicate_coefs <- function(filter_coefs, n){
  rep(filter_coefs, each = `^`(2, n - as.integer(log2(length(filter_coefs))) ))
}


microbenchmark(
  old = {
    #Square matrix to write data
    MyMatrix <- matrix(, nrow = n, ncol = 2 ^ n)


    row <- 0 #row counter
    for (vector in HaarData@W) {
      row <- row + 1
      duplication <- (2 ^ n) / length(vector)
      newRow <- c(rep(vector, each = duplication))
      MyMatrix[row,] <- newRow
    }
  }
  ,
  new = {
     n_len <- length(HaarData@W)
     new_result <- matrix(unlist( lapply(HaarData@W, duplicate_coefs, n_len) )
            , nrow = n_len
            , byrow = TRUE)

)

identical(MyMatrix, new_result)
```

On my machine you get about 50x speed-up

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
  old 2891.967 2940.0550 3203.14740 2982.5360 3110.3985 6472.223   100
  new   48.519   50.8065   59.04673   56.4805   60.8905  302.845   100
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks ( I want to make principal component analysis on the wavelet coefficients). Here, a prize for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT2hFTKCXx4

Comment: Well, you might want to take a look at the [irlba](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irlba/index.html) package, which implements an algo to do the PCA directly on a sparse matrix - the default representation of wavelet coefs. Instead of making the matrix dense and then doing the PCA ;)